# Intellij, turn off automatic context info popups during editing

Tags: intellij-idea

Alt+Q shows the context of where I'm editing, the name of the inner class, class, etc, by pressing it repeatedly.

But it does it automatically all the time, and it is making the editor very sluggish. I can't seem to find an option turn this auto context popup info off.... I want it to be off, while still being able to pop it up using Alt+Q.

Comment: Found this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142588
It seems this "tooltip" can not be disabled. I find that strange because it really interferes with moving the cursor around in the editor. There a quite a pause that slow things down.

Comment: Turns out that it isn't context info that is causing the delays. It is the Indent Guides that is causing it. Turning them off makes the delays go away completely.